# cannot use http response array after putting it in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

I am using AngularJs in my application. I make a `http` call and getting the response. The response contains an array which I am putting as `result`inside the `$scope` object. I am placing a `watch` on some attribute and try to access the stored object put inside the $scope object. If I print the `result` object, I see that it contains the array, but when I try to use the array properties such as `length` it throws an error. I am also not able to use other array methods such as `results.data[0]`.

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Some code for understanding purpose:

```
var processResponse = function (result) {
          $scope.results = result.data;
      }

$scope.$watch('attribute', function(newVal) {
        console.log($scope.results.length)
      });
```

Comment: can you show the logs

Comment: Got it. Since it is a ajax and asynchronous when I tried to print the length, the results was not yet added to the scope. Hence it was throwing Typer error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depend how you call this. If the result is a promisse you can try do it:

`result.then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution which I will use. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just try to declare/init $scope.results = []; at the top of your controller.
Then the method length couldn't crash ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since it was asynchronous request, I had to take care of null by the following code:

```
if ($scope.results && $scope.results.data){
    console.log($scope.results.data.length);
}
```